# clearing_radius costmap

Tags: navigation, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have one question with this parameter in the navigation stack.

I have already running the move_base node with fake_localize, base_local_planner, base_global_planner and works great but I have some troubles because the ugv goes very near of the walls. I try to change this parameters:

clearing_radius
inflation_radius

but I can't change the global_planner to make the path very near of the obstacles, the robot goes with the same distance with the difference that it can't go inside some places (maybe because the inflation_radius).

I want the robot goes a little far from the walls (about 30-40 cm).
Can anybody tell me how this parameters work? I don't find any documentation.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/37175/clearing_radius-costmap/) by [pmarinplaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1959/pmarinplaza/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2012-06-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, At least I found the correct parameter:

occdist_scale

This parameter causes the robot goes little far from walls.

```
# Trajectory Scoring Parameters
    goal_distance_bias: 0.8
    path_distance_bias: 0.6
    occdist_scale: 0.2 #0.01
    heading_lookahead: 0.325
    dwa: true
```

Thanks for the info, you help me very much

---

Originally posted by [pmarinplaza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1959/pmarinplaza/) with karma: 330 on 2012-06-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think you need to increase the costs for cells close to obstacles. In addition to the `inflation_radius` parameter that you already found, I would play around with the `cost_scaling_factor` parameter. The formula that is uses to calculate cost values can be found [here](http://ros.org/wiki/costmap_2d).

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-06-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1